# Как создать скрипт seeds.rb? ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Необходимо создать скрипт seeds.rb, который сможет записывать информацию в базу данных из файла seeds.yml. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?
вопрос взят из задания http://webnmobile.tumblr.com/post/122866067493/2-mvc-with-ruby-on-rails. Просьба помочь разобраться в данном вопросе.
Информацию искал несколько дней но так и не нашел ничего такого, что могло бы мне помочь. Спасибо

Comment: То есть вы вбили в гугл «rails seeds» и первые три ссылки в результатах поиска вам почему-то никак не помогли? Почему?

Comment: Не помогли к сожалению. Код упрямо не хочет работать.

Comment: Покажите код и тексты ошибок в таком случае

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предположить, что у вас есть:

1. модель `Project` c полем `title` и ассоциацией `has_many :todos`
2. модель `Todo` c полями `title` и `isCompleted` и ассоциацией `belongs_to :project`

то примерно так:

```rb
# db/seeds.rb
require 'yaml'
# Парсим данные из yml файла
data = YAML.load_file('seeds.yml')
# Получаем массив проектов (получается массив хешей)
projects = data[:projects]
# Для каждого проекта из массива:
projects.each do |project|
  # Создаем новый проект в БД
  created_project = Project.create!(title: project[:title])
  # Создаем для нового проекта todos
  created_project.todos.create!(project[:todos])
end
```